# How to use git alias with shell function to build a commit message

Tags: bash, git, shell

I'm trying to create a git alias to automate my PR merge and approval.

The complete git command is this:

`git checkout master && git sync && git merge --no-ff -m 'Merged in hotfix/X-3144 (pull request #1112)' remotes/origin/hotfix/X-3144`

Where X is the BitBucket prefix for the issue. Reading other stack overflow questions, I came up with this:

```
mergeto = "!f() { git checkout $1 && git sync && git merge --no-ff -m 'Merged in {$2}/B2B-{$3} (pull request #{$4})' remotes/origin/$2/X-$3;}; f "
```

So, naturally I'm using this to merge a PR that has conflicts. After I resolve these conflicts, I issue a `git commit` and git brings up nano with my previously typed commit message. My goal here is that the commit message is constructed using my parameters. So, for an example, if I use:

`git mergeto master hotfix 123 1120`

My final commit message was supposed to be "Merged in hotfix/X-123 (pull request #1120)" but instead I get a "Merged in {$2}/X-{$3} (pull request #{$4})"

How can I specify the parameters in such a way that this can work?

I Read a few stack over flow posts that show how to use a shell function inside a git alias, but couldn't find an example of escaping the text with parameters.

Comment: That is because you want to use variable expansion but using single quote. That is not gonna hold water.

Comment: Because parameter substitution does not happen in single quotes.  Change them to double quotes and escape them with a backslash and you should be good.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using [John Szakmeister](https://stackoverflow.com/users/683080/john-szakmeister) and [eftshift0](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2437508/eftshift0) suggestions, I got it working by escaping double quotes with backlash:

```
mergeto = "!f() { git checkout $1 && git sync && git merge --no-ff -m \"Merged in $2/B2B-$3 (pull request #$4)\" remotes/origin/$2/X-$3;}; f "
```

Thanks for your help!